# Time associated with dropping a table

Tags: sql, database

Does the time it takes to drop a table in SQL reflect the quantity of data within the table?

Lets say for dropping an identical table one with 100000 rows and 1000 rows.

Comment: I did try in a Java application I am making, with no time difference. I was going to exlude further testing of this, however I felt it was important to establish if at some point size of the database may increase time, that my friend is not somthing I know.

Comment: In my experience, at least for MySQL it takes around ... zero time. Pretty much as long as `rm -f database-file` would take. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: What RDBMS? SQL Server uses deferred drop for large tables so they are are dropped in the background after a transaction has committed.

Comment: Thanks Damon, that is what I have found (Also in MySQL, will check postgre, oracle and firebird), but shall not pursue testing anymore than one size drop, thanks!

Comment: @Damon: I wouldn't say so: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/20/drop-table-performance/

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Or are you interested in all of them?

Comment: Hi WW, Postgre, MySQL, Oracle and Firebird.... although getting them all to work on the different servers in prooving to be little fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this MySQL? The ext3 Linux filesystem is known to be slow to drop large tables. The time to drop will have to do more with the size of the table, more than the rows in the table.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/06/16/slow-drop-table/

Comment: Interesting, well then potentially I should run some tests, thanks.

Comment: Some new article from percona: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/20/drop-table-performance/

Comment: Thankyou, it appears that with everything said, it would be worth testing a little further.

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely depend on the dbserver and on the specific storage params in that db server and upon the existence of LOBs in the table. For MOST scenarios, it's very fast.

Comment: Hi MJB, I shall test Ubuntu Server, Solaris Server and Windows 2008 Server with Postgre, MySQL, Oracle and Firebird RDBMS. Within my application which reports to 1000th of a second, I am getting a display of 0.0 for each drop....

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, dropping a table is very quick and unlikely to matter compared to other operations you would be performing (creating the table and populating it).

It would not be idomatic to be creating and dropping tables enough in Oracle for this to be any sort of a performance factor.  You would instead consider using global temporary tables.

From http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm

> In addition to permanent tables,
>   Oracle Database can create temporary
>   tables to hold session-private data
>   that exists only for the duration of a
>   transaction or session.
>
> The CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
>   statement creates a temporary table
>   that can be transaction-specific or
>   session-specific. For
>   transaction-specific temporary tables,
>   data exists for the duration of the
>   transaction. For session-specific
>   temporary tables, data exists for the
>   duration of the session. Data in a
>   temporary table is private to the
>   session. Each session can only see and
>   modify its own data. DML locks are not
>   acquired on the data of the temporary
>   tables. The LOCK statement has no
>   effect on a temporary table, because
>   each session has its own private data.